# Cascade require in NodeJs, require a file which requires another file NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I have a file.
**a.js**

```
class A{
  constructor(name){
        this.name = name;
    }

  displayName(){
    console.log(this.name);
  }
}
module.exports = A;
```

Another file
**common.js**

```
const A = require('./a');
exports.A;
```

Another file **b.js**

```
const common  = require('./common');
var a = new common.A('My name is khan and I am not a terrorist');
a.displayName();
```

I am getting an error *A is not a constructor*. 
Please help, how can get it done.
Please forgive my silly mistakes, I am newbie.

Comment: well in a.js you should be doing : module.exports = A

Comment: and to be consistent in ``common.js`` **module.exports = A**

Comment: I am sorry, its  module.exports = A only. Let me edit in question.

Comment: @lomboboo added module.exports = A; still the same error.

Comment: @Imran see my answer below...

Comment: Thanks @evvels1. Worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the fixes that you should make...

In the `a.js` file, you're exporting `Render`, however, it should be `A` instead...

```
class A {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    displayName() {
        console.log(this.name);
    }
}
module.exports = A;
```

In your `common.js` file, you have to export an `object` that consist of the `common` classes/functions/variables, or whatever, like the following:

```
const A = require('./a');
const someOtherVariable = 'Hello World!';
module.exports = {
    A: A,
    someOtherVariable: someOtherVariable,
};
```

***Comment:*** the reason you "have to" is because you want to use the `A` class with the following syntax: `common.A`... Assuming the name of the file is `common`, you will probably `export` more than just that one `class`, so package them into an `object`...

Lastly, in the `b.js` file, you can then use the `common.A` syntax to extract the class you are looking to use...

```
const common = require('./common');
const a = new common.A('My name is khan');
a.displayName();
console.log(common.someOtherVariable); // Hello World!
```

Hope this helps.